# Applying derivative instead of typing it

Tags: sympy, derivative

In this code, function and its derivative are intended to be type in, since Eval accepts strings:

```
def newton(func, deriv, x, n):
    def f(x):
        f =eval(func)
        return f
    def df(x):
        df =eval(deriv)
        return df
    for h in range(1,n):
        i = x - (f(x)/df(x))
        x = i
```

But what if we wish the machine to advise us the derivative, making the input like:

```
newton(str(y),str(y.diff), 2,10)
```

The output is "bound method Expr.diff of x**2 + 1". Is the a way to fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Strings don't know how to calculate a derivative but (if you really want to do it this way) you need a string that represents the derivative of the function described by the string `y`. So create a SymPy object that knows how to take the derivative, take the derivative, then convert it back to a string:

```
>>> y = 'x**2 + 1'
>>> newton(y, str(S(y).diff()), 2, 10)
```

(Your function won't show you anything, however, without a return statement.)